# Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions'

Tags: dotnetnuke

After upgrading my DNN Website from 6.1.3 to 8.0.0 I am getting following message on every page

Module Load Warning
One or more of the modules on this page did not load. This may be temporary. Please refresh the page (click F5 in most browsers). If the problem persists, please let the Site Administrator know.

After further debugging I found following error in the log.resources file

System.Web.HttpParseException: Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions'

Can someone help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DNN8 Eliminated the SolPartActions type which is typically referenced in your Containers.  Go to your Containers folder: /Portals/x/Containers and open each .ascx file.

Look for and REMOVE two things:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="ACTIONS" Src="~/Admin/Containers/SolPartActions.ascx" %>
```

and

```
<dnn:ACTIONS runat="server" id="dnnACTIONS" />
```

Comment: Great! Please accept and vote on the answer if it works for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove/Comment the following things on each .aspx page under currently used "portal templates" folders.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="ACTIONS" Src="~/Admin/Containers/Actions.ascx" %>
```

or

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="ACTIONS" Src="~/Admin/Containers/SolPartActions.ascx" %>
```

AND

```
<dnn:ACTIONS runat="server" id="dnnACTIONS"  ProviderName="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" ExpandDepth="1" PopulateNodesFromClient="True" />
```

or

```
<dnn:ACTIONS runat="server" id="dnnACTIONS" />
```

because,
They are removing the following navigation providers on DNN 8+ versions

ASP2MenuNavigationProvider

DNNDropDownNavigationProvider

DNNMenuNavigationProvider

DNNTreeNavigationProvider

SolpartMenuNavigationProvider